# How can I detect client disconnection using sockets?

Tags: java, php, sockets, tcp, websocket

**Goal**

I am using sockets to implement an instant messaging app with a chat roulette feature.
If 2 clients are talking, and 1 disconnects, then the other needs to know.
A disconnection includes both graceful and ungraceful disconnections (i.e. your phone dying).

**Current Strategy**

Off the top of my head, my strategy is to have each client ping the server about every 5 seconds (which serves as a kind of "heartbeat").  If a client misses an interval, the server will let the other client know.

**Concerns**

This doesn't seem like it will scale very well.  The server would have to use a listener per client.  And having thousands or millions of clients ping the server sounds pretty brutal.

**Question**

How can I determine client disconnection relatively quickly while being able to scale?

**Side Notes**

Server-side is in php.  Client-side is in java.

Comment: You do realize that orderly client shut-down will close the socket and the server will be notified of that immediately.  Pings can be used to detect abnormal shut-down and shouldn't need to be super frequent.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you.  I know I can instantly detect graceful disconnections, but my design involved having a single script running on the server all the time.  So pinging the server for non-graceful disconnections seemed like it could overwhelm the cpu executing this script.  But after reading your response, I realized I can just have a client query my database to check if the other user is still online.  If the the other user is offline, but I haven't received a notification from the server, then this implies a non-graceful disconnection.  This won't overload a single process on the server.